# Spring Integration: Stategies for avoiding lost messages

Tags: spring-integration

If a Spring Integration channel is defined with a task executor, a thread pool will be used to handle messages as they come in. If a service activator or transformer endpoint component receives messages from this internal channel, will a pool of endpoint components be instantiated, one for each thread? If this is not the default behaviour, what configuration is required in order to achieve this?

This is important for two reasons:

1. So that the service activator/transformer which receives the messages will not be a bottleneck.
2. To ensure that the endpoint component handles messages in the same thread that the internal channel uses, so they are part of the same transaction. If this is the case and the channel is persisted using JMS, messages will not be lost. Otherwise, if the endpoint run in a separate transaction, the fact that the messages are persited on the channel will not help if there is a JVM failure once a message has been passed to the endpoint component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No; there is one instance of each endpoint, regardless of the threading on in the input channel.

1. You avoid "bottlenecks" by careful design of the service by, typically, making it stateless.
2. It is not clear what you mean; if the channel is backed by JMS, each thread on the output side can get its own transaction and mesages will be rolled back onto the queue in the event of a service failure. This is completely different to a simple executor channel (for which transactions can never work, and having a separate instance won't help either).

Perhaps if you can describe a specific use case /  configuration, someone can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Here is an example to clarify my question:

Comment: Here is an example to clarify my question: an internal channel is defined with a task executor. Messages are placed on the channel by an inbound channel adapter which polls a database. A transformer then receives messages from the internal channel. My understanding is that the internal (executor) channel will not be part of any preceding transaction, but that it will begin a new transaction which will include the transformer. In that case, even if there is a failure after the channel has handed over the message to the transformer, the message will not be lost. Is this correct?

Comment: To clarify the above, when I say that the message will be persisted and not lost, I am referring to an executor channel which is backed by jms (<jms:channel ... />)

Comment: Again, you are confusing an executor channel with a jms-backed channel. An executor channel simply hands off to another thread; transactional semantics depend on whatever is downstream of the channel (`@Transactional` methods, a transactional gateway, etc). With a JMS-backed channel, it can be configured to use transactions and the transaction starts with the message retrieval from the queue and it won't be lost in the event of a failure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So <int-jms:channel task-executor="..." acknowledge="transacted"/> will start a new transaction, which will include the downstream endpoints (service filter, transformer etc). If there is a system failure, even after the message is handed over to the endpoint, the message will not have been lost because the JMS provider (if so configured) have been persisted it.